# Probability that the drawn balls are from the second urn

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

**Question:**
We have three urns. In the first urn, there are **1 red**, **2 blue**, and **3 green** balls. 
In the second urn, there are **2 red**, **1 blue**, and **4 green** balls. 
In the third urn, there are **5 red**, **4 blue**, and **3 green** balls. 
We randomly choose one urn and draw two balls from it. One of the drawn balls is **red**, and the other is **green**.
What is the probability that the drawn balls are from the **second urn**?

**My approach:**
So i'll start with the probability of drawing one red ball and one green ball from the second urn: $$\frac{2}{7} * \frac{4}{6}$$
Then i'll add the chance of choosing the second urn which $\dfrac{1}{3}$ 
After that i will use probability of drawing one red ball and one green ball from all of them $$\frac{1}{6} * \frac{3}{5} * \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{7} * \frac{4}{6} * \frac{1}{3} + \frac{5}{12} * \frac{3}{11} * \frac{1}{3}$$
Then i would use Bayes' theorem to get the probability.
$$\dfrac{\frac{2}{7} * \frac{4}{6}* \frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{6} * \frac{3}{5} * \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{7} * \frac{4}{6} * \frac{1}{3} + \frac{5}{12} * \frac{3}{11} * \frac{1}{3}}$$

Is my approach correct or did I make a mistake ? Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit: Changed denominator (one less ball) when choosing the second ball**

Comment: "*We randomly choose one urn and draw two balls from it*"  This usually means that both balls will be simultaneously removed from the urn... implying they can not be the same exact ball.  You shouldn't have $\dfrac{2}{7}\times\dfrac{4}{7}$ but rather $\dfrac{2}{7}\times\dfrac{4}{6}$.  That is, typically the problem is interpreted that the balls are drawn *without replacement*.  Similarly, the other denominators should have decreased with each draw.

Comment: The drawing is to be taken as without replacement unless specifically stated otherwise.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the help! @JMoravitz and true-blue-anil